# Application_controller define method to only show future dates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, drop-down-menu, where-clause

In my  Ruby on Rails application I have a cinema system and am trying to show only show times for films that are either in the future or today (so not in the past).

I am trying to do this in my _form.html.erb in a drop down menu:

```
<%= f.grouped_collection_select :showing_id, live_films.order(:title), :showings, :title, :id,  :showing_times %>
```

Where `live_films` is the method in application_controller.rb:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
# Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
# For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
protect_from_forgery with: :exception

helper_method :active_menu, :live_films  

def live_films 
    Film.includes(:showings).where('showings.show_date > ?', Date.current.beginning_of_day)
end
end
```

But I get this error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Bookings#new
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: showings.show_date: SELECT "films".* FROM "films" WHERE (showings.show_date > '2015-02-20 00:00:00.000000')  ORDER BY "films"."title" ASC
```

My db/schema:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150219091141) do

create_table "bookings", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "showing_id"
    t.integer  "seat_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end

create_table "categories", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "genre"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end

create_table "certificates", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "age_rating"
    t.datetime "created_at",          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",          null: false
    t.string   "certificate_img_url"
end

create_table "films", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.string   "synopsis"
    t.string   "director"
    t.string   "cast1"
    t.string   "cast2"
    t.string   "cast3"
    t.date     "release_date"
    t.string   "warnings"
    t.datetime "created_at",     null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",     null: false
    t.string   "image_url"
    t.string   "certificate_id"
    t.integer  "category_id"
    t.integer  "hours"
    t.integer  "minutes"
    t.string   "video_url"
end

create_table "screens", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end

create_table "seats", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "row_letter"
    t.integer  "row_number"
    t.integer  "screen_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end

create_table "showings", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.date     "show_date"
    t.time     "show_time"
    t.integer  "film_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer  "screen_id"
end

add_index "showings", ["film_id"], name: "index_showings_on_film_id"

create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "password_digest"
    t.string   "role"
    t.datetime "created_at",      null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",      null: false
    t.string   "first_name"
    t.string   "last_name"
    t.string   "house_no"
    t.string   "street"
    t.string   "town"
    t.string   "postcode"
    t.string   "email"
end
```

The column name `show_date` is correct as is the table name `showings` but for some reason it isn't working.

Can someone please help?

Comment: Show your db schema (`db/schema.rb` file).

Comment: Maybe this is because you try to do an operation of datetime column on date typed column. try doing the range check only with date (without the time)

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: Try something like `Date.current.to_s(:db)` instead of `Date.current.beginning_of_day`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

```
Film.joins(:showings).where('showings.show_date > ?', Date.current.beginning_of_day).preload(:showings)
```